# copy a file from AWS S3 to a docker container when the container is building and an MFA code is required from google authenticator

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose

I have a file located in an S3 bucket:
In the docker file, I can actually successfully obtain the file by echoing the MFA into the s3 copy.

```
RUN echo 999999 | aws s3 cp s3://s3/mssql/${BACKUP}.bak /usr/work/${BACKUP}.bak
```

This actually works just fine, the 999999 is the MFA code from google authenticator that needs to supplied to the S3 copy in order to succeed.

My problem is that this MFA code needs to be prompted for by the docker build process, not echoed.

```
RUN aws s3 cp s3://s3/mssql/${BACKUP}.bak /usr/work/${BACKUP}.bak
```

This does not work because tty input does not appear to be available during the build process. I cannot get the prompt to actually work at all.

I have tried setting these flags in the docker-compose.yml file, but this applies when the container RUNS not when the container BUILDS.

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

There is a further issue, assume that I supply the MFA code as an environment variable, then the container might take longer to build than the expiry time of the MFA code.

Is there a way to obtain a token or some other longer lasting security context that can be passed into the docker-compose so that it can obtain the file whilst building.

Alternatively is there a way to prompt for input whilst a container is building?